# How can I create sql-based calculation view pragmatically

Tags: hana

I am working on a cloud product and I need to create sql-based calculation view. But I should not use hana studio because I need to create calculation view on different databases and using hana studio to create it manually is painful and error-prone.
How can I create it pragmatically ?

Comment: What do you mean by “sql-based calculation views”?

Comment: For sql-based calculation view, I mean: http://teachmehana.com/sap-hana-scripted-calculation-view-sql/

Comment: Yeah, these are deprecated and table typed user defined functions TUDF should be used now.

Comment: Thanks, I am quite new to this, can you let me know how I can use TUDF to filter Calc-View? I want to be able to filter results of calc-view based on a session variable, if I can define some where clause, that would be good enough.

Comment: Have a look into the documentation. It's literally explained in there how you use TUDFs in Calc Views and what options (e.g. `APPLY_FILTER`) you have to filter sets.